# Replacing a pre-defined integer with its corresponding String in C

Tags: c

It was kind of difficult to make a title for this thread but anyhow, I do have a couple of `DEFINE` in the beginning of my `C` code as following:

```
#define LOAD  2
#define UP    1
#define STOP  0
#define DOWN -1
```

They are `state` names in my particular state diagram. Now, I need to print these state names with `printf` command but I don't know how to retrieve the textual equivalent of state names. For instance, assume `state` is initially declared as:

```
int state = STOP;
```

I would like to have something like:

```
printf("Current State: %s,  state);
```

which results to:

> Current State: STOP

I know I can mimic this with four `if` but I was wondering if there is an easier way of achieving this.

Thanks

Comment: you could define a lookup to store these strings so that lookup[-1] = "DOWN", lookup[0] = "STOP" ,..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need to keep the state DOWN to have the value -1 you have to take special care when using it to access array elements.

Given that your state values are in the range of [-1 .. N-1] you could just add a constant 1 to them to get indices [0 .. N] that can be used to address the elements of a char* array.

```
const char* const state_names[] = {"down","stop","up","load"};
```

This only works well as long as you have a continuous numerical sequence. If you later add a state `#define WHATEVER 1000` this approach will fail. When you change values of your states, you have to reorder your string array accordingly.

If you want to keep the value associated with your state flexible, I would recommend using lookup tables for state name and value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum {LOAD, UP, STOP, DOWN};

const char* const state_names[] = 
{
    [LOAD] = "load",
    [UP]   = "up",
    [STOP] = "stop",
    [DOWN] = "down"
};

const int state_values[] = 
{
    [LOAD] = 2,
    [UP]   = 1,
    [STOP] = 0,
    [DOWN] = -1
};

int main()
{
    int state = STOP;

    printf("Current State Name:  %s\n",  state_names[state]);
    printf("Current State Value: %i\n",  state_values[state]);

    return 0;
}
```

This way, order or actual value of a state do not matter any more, you can easily add more states or reorder them without breaking the code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may use a string array:

```
#define LOAD  2
#define UP    1
#define STOP  0
#define DOWN -1

int main ()
{
    const char *my_array[] = {"DOWN","STOP","UP","LOAD"};
    int state = STOP;

    printf("Current State: %s,  my_array[state+ 1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: would add lookup = my_array + 1; .. printf .. lookup[state].. less error prone than remembering to add 1 everytime you want to print the state